# ASP.NET MVC Unit Testing with Repository Pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit-2.5

I am trying to get my feet wet with asp.net mvc3 and unit testing.

I have created a model which uses the repository pattern.  Here's the interface:

```
public interface IExtensionRepository
{
    IList<Extensions> ListAll();
}
```

Here's the repository:

```
public class ExtensionRepository : IExtensionRepository
{
    private ExtensionsLSDataContext _dataContext;

    public ExtensionRepository()
    {
        _dataContext = new ExtensionsLSDataContext();
    }

    public IList<Extensions> ListAll()
    {
        var extensions = from ext in _dataContext.Extensions
                         select ext;
        return extensions.ToList();
    }

}
```

Here's the controller:

```
public class ExtensionController : Controller
{

    private IExtensionRepository _repository;

    public ExtensionController()
        : this(new ExtensionRepository())
    {

    }

    public ExtensionController(IExtensionRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
 }
```

The pages seem to function as designed.  Things go astray with my unit test, however.  It resides in another project in the same solution.  I am using Moq and NUnit.  Here's my test:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_Extension_Index_Views()
    {
        Mock<Extensions> extension = new Mock<Extensions>();
        List<Extensions> extList = new List<Extensions>();
        extension.Object.Extension = "5307";
        extension.Object.Extension_ID = 1;
        extension.Object.ExtensionGroup_ID = 1;
        extList.Add(extension.Object);

        Mock<IExtensionRepository> repos = new Mock<IExtensionRepository>();
        repos.Setup(er => er.ListAll()).Returns(extList);

        var controller = new ExtensionController(repos);                       


        var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName);
    }
```

I am getting the following errors for the line that begins "var controller...":

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'MvcApplication1.Controllers.ExtensionController.ExtensionController(MvcApplication1.Models.IExtensionRepository)'
>   has some invalid arguments

And:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'Moq.Mock'
>   to
>   'MvcApplication1.Models.IExtensionRepository'

I know I've missed the boat somewhere, but I haven't a clue as to where... any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this:

```
var controller = new ExtensionController(repos);
```

to this:

```
var controller = new ExtensionController(repos.Object);
```

PS.: I know it sucks, but that's the way Moq was designed.

Comment: that did the trick!  Thanks for your help with a rookie mistake.